# How to Fix Error in ManiFest on app Flutter

Tags: android, flutter

I'm new in flutter and I need to use BlE and Beacon on the app so I using Library [beacons_plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/beacons_plugin#-readme-tab-)  But When I make Write the Steps to implantation the Library  i discovery i have multiple  Error in the Manifest i don't whet the problem and How does it work when there are mistakes please any Body Help me How can I Solution it   [image]
[image]